# Setting Up CI/CD Pipelines for Power Platform Application Using Service Principal and SSL Certificate

Tags: azure-pipelines, ssl-certificate, connector, azure-service-principal, power-platform

Currently setting up ci/cd pipelines a power platform application. Would like to connect to power platform to perform the various task using service principal and SSL certificate (NOT client secret). Is there a way to achieve this (i.e., custom connector)? Currently the Power Platform connector only allows for client secret.

use connector using SSL Cert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Power Platform tasks from the extension: [Power Platform Build Tools (2.0.49)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=microsoft-IsvExpTools.PowerPlatform-BuildTools&ssr=false#overview), the Power Platform Service Connection doesn't support using service principal and SSL certificate.

It only supports using service principal and Client Secret for the time being.

For example:

[image]

I am afraid that there is no method can use service principal and SSL certificate to create service connection, then use it in the Power Platform tasks from the extension.

I can fully understand your requirement. You can report the feature in this site: [Platform Tool feedback](https://github.com/microsoft/powerplatform-build-tools/issues)

For a workaround, you can change to use the [PAC CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/cli/reference/auth#named-create-with-service-principal) to use service principal and SSL certificate for authentication.

For example:

```
pac auth create --name MyOrg-SPN --applicationId 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --certificateDiskPath xxx  --certificatePassword xxx --tenant 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

In this case, the authentication completed by command cannot be passed to the Power Platform task.

So the subsequent operations also need to be completed using the PAC CLI.